# Accretion of in-falling material for a young main sequence star

Tags: protostar, main-sequence

I'm reading material that is seemingly contradictory.  Some sources indicate that the evolution of a protostar to a main sequence star is characterised by a stellar wind that precludes the accretion of further in-falling material.  That is, the (young) star now has a constant mass.  However, other sources suggest that material may continue to accrete for a (brief) period after the protostar has become a main sequence star.

Can someone please confirm the actual process?

Comment: Could you provide information on what materials you are reading? It may be useful in clarifying the contradiction.

Comment: Hi Mitch, my sources indicating the cessation of accretion once the stellar wind is formed include "Pathways to Astronomy" (Schneider & Arny), and the attached link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protostar#Classes_of_Protostars.  The potential for accretion to continue for a brief period after the protostar has become a main sequence star is suggested here: http://www2.cose.isu.edu/~hackmart/stellarevo.pdf

Comment: Is this the part that threw you off? _"Material continues to flow onto new stars for some
time after ignition.. The energy from infalling material
exceeds, in some cases, the energy from nuclear
fusion in young stars.."_

Comment: Yes, that was the paragraph confusing me!  However, I think Ed has clarified my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the protostar phase a vigorous outflow from the star develops called the T-Tauri Wind and this could cut off accretion.  Eventually, it develops into a normal star and the strong wind dies down.  Material that was not totally blown away could then continue to  fall down and be accreted

Comment: Thanks Ed, however could you please share your sources so that I can read further?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_wind